# Is there a way to correctly use sanitize_text_field and wp_unslash that doesn't cause psalm to error with "expects string, possibly different type"

Tags: php, wordpress-plugin-creation, psalm-php

I am writing a WordPress plugin, and need to correctly unslash and sanitise a variable in PHP.
I am using psalm as my static analysis tool, and it is identifying my code as containing a potential error:

```
// Check your nonce.
if ( isset( $_POST['_wpnonce'] ) ) {
    if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( sanitize_text_field( wp_unslash( $_POST['_wpnonce'] ) ) ) ) {
            // other code here
    }
}
```

Psalm shows this an an error (or warning, depending on the psalm level I set):

```
Argument 1 of sanitize_text_field expects string, possibly different type array<array-key, mixed>|string provided
```

I have tried various other ways of arranging the code above to prevent psalm from not presenting this warning, but I am unable to. (Yes, I am a aware that the reason the message is being displayed is because wp_unslash *can* return an string *or* an array).

For example, if I split the code up:

```
// Check your nonce.
if ( isset( $_POST['_wpnonce'] ) ) {
    $unslashed = wp_unslash( $_POST['_wpnonce'] );
    $sanitized = sanitize_text_field( $unslashed );
    if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $sanitized ) ) {
        // other code here
    }
}
```

I then get the following psalm error:

```
Detected usage of a non-sanitized input variable: $_POST['_wpnonce']
```

Is there a way to arrange this code (without supressing the message) that will keep psalm happy, and also keep inline with the WordPress Coding Standards (e.g. you should unslash *before* you sanitize)?

Comment: What exactly does `wp_unslash($_POST['_wpnonce']))` return? Would casting not fix this? `(string)`

Comment: wp_unslash can return string|array.
Problem with casting it is that psalm whinges that you cannot cast an array to a string.

Comment: What if you implement a check prior like `!is_array()` just to keep `psalm` happy

Comment: If I do something like `! is_array(wp_unslash($_POST['_wpnonce']))) && ` ... then it whinges that `"Detected usage of a non-sanitized input variable: $_POST['_wpnonce']"`, as I haven't used `sanitize_text_field()`. It's the combination of having to use `wp_unslash()` and `sanitize_text_field()` together that's the issue.

Answer (score 4):

You can use sanitize_key() to sanitize WP nonce. The following gets passed in WPCS

```
if ( isset( $_POST['_wpnonce'] ) && wp_verify_nonce( sanitize_key( $_POST['_wpnonce'] ) ) ) {
    echo 'hi';
}
```